sv_ttk dark theme not working consistently
I have two methods that create and use tkinter windows with sv_ttk dark theme. One method, which consists of text box, scrollbar, and button, works perfectly. The second method, which consists of entries, labels, and a button, dark theme does not work at all.
The windows are called the exact same way and the windows aren't used outside the method that creates and destroys them.
    # Create root window, make it appear on top, and set title
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    root.title("User Input")

    # Set dark theme
    sv_ttk.set_theme('dark')

Any idea why the entry/label method doesn't apply dark theme?

Most probably you have create more than one instance of tk.Tk().  Try using sv_ttk.set_theme('dark', root) instead.  Or use tk.Toplevel() for the second window.


I have two methods that create and use tkinter windows with sv_ttk
dark theme. One method, which consists of text box, scrollbar, and
button, works perfectly. The second method, which consists of entries,
labels, and a button, dark theme does not work at all.

The problem can be fixed.

Add from tkinter import ttk to the module.
Add ttk. prefix in second method

Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk
 

# Create root window, make it appear on top, and set title
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.title("User Input")

# Set dark theme
sv_ttk.set_theme('dark')

def sample():
    text_box = tk.Text(root)

    text_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

    text_box.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    sb.config(command=text_box.yview)

    btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1")
    btn.grid(row=1, column=0)


def sample_1():
    label = ttk.Label(root, text=r"sv_ttk dark theme not working consistently")
    label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry.grid(row=3, column=0)

    button = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2")
    button.grid(row=4, column=0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    sample()
    sample_1()
    root.mainloop()

Screenshot:


Never end up getting it to work perfectly using built-in theme. Did end up changing tk.Label/Entry/Frame to ttk.Label/Entry/Frame but Label and Frame never did work properly.
Created custom style using ttk.Style() for Frame and Labels which worked.

Yes. It will function with the frame. You didn't mention it in your original post.
